# How to pass QPixmap from a C++ model to QML?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, model-view-controller, icons

I use QAbstractItemModel to provide icons for all sorts of things in the context of a keyboard launcher.

These are the requirements:

- The frontend is abstract, hence the model should be applicable for Widgets as well as QML views. This comes with the restriction that the decoration role cant return QIcons (afaik).
- The backend should be platform agnostic. On linux I use [`QMimeDatabase::mimeTypeForFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html#mimeTypeForFile) > [`QMimeType::iconName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimetype.html#iconName-prop) > [`QIcon::fromTheme`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme). On macOS Qt does not provide such facilities, therefore I plan to use [`icon(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3553230-icon) which returns `NSImage`, which I would have to draw into a QPixmap.

No icons, no paths. Theres only QPixmap left, right? Is this the way to go? Can I display a QPixmap from a C++ model in QML at all? Or should I cache the icon on disk and pass a path in the model?

Another requirement is that this should be reasonably fast since its a keyboard launcher and results should show up instantly.

Comment: Why do you think that the model cannot return `QIcon`? AFAIK, this is not true.

Comment: _Can I pass QPixmap from a C++ model to QML at all?_ Take a look at [`Qt::DecorationRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum): The data to be rendered as a decoration in the form of an icon. (QColor, QIcon or QPixmap)

Comment: I am making an example for you. Pleas, stand by.

Comment: Sure the model can return any QVariant, but the QML view cannot make use of QIcon afaik. @scopchanov edited the question. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r, I am almost there. ;) Please wait.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r, Have you tried my solution? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

I must admit, it is not as straightforward as I wish it were, but here it is anyway:

Provide the model from the C++ backend, e.g.:

```
class Backend : public QObject
{
    ...
    QStandardItemModel *model() const { return m_model; }
    ...

private:
    QStandardItemModel *m_model;
};
```

Use a [`QQuickImageProvider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) subclass to get the pixmap of the decoration role for the given model index like that:

```
QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *, const QSize &) override {
    const QModelIndex &index(m_model->index(id.toInt(), 0));
    const QIcon &icon(m_model->data(index, Qt::DecorationRole).value<QIcon>());

    return icon.pixmap(QSize(16, 16));
}
```

In `main.cpp` you need the following code:

```
Backend backend;

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", &backend);
engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("icons"), new PixmapBuilder(backend.model()));

qmlRegisterUncreatableType<QStandardItemModel>("QStandardItemModel", 1, 0, "QStandardItemModel", "The model should be created in C++");
```

Finally set the sourse of the `Image` component in QML like that:

```
Image {
    id: name
    source: "image://icons/" + index
}
```

### Example

On GitHub you can find [an example](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-QmlCppModelIcons) I wrote for you to demonstrate the proposed solution.

### Result

The example produces the following result:

[image: Program window with a decorated list]